# Validar dados do formulário com registro na base de dados

Tags: asp.net, mvc

Estou desenvolver com o ASP.NET MVC (utilizo ENTITIES/DAL/LOGIC - camadas) e queria saber melhor modo de validar dados do formulário (do website)para ficar registado na base de dados?
Tenho na camada DAL (acesso à BD - SQL) este código:

```
 public void CriaRegisto(JogadorDTO jogadorDTO)
        {
            bd_AvesEntities baseDados = new bd_AvesEntities();
            tbJogadores tabelaJogador = new tbJogadores();

            tabelaJogador.NumeroCamisola = jogadorDTO.NumeroCamisola;
            tabelaJogador.Nome = jogadorDTO.Nome;
            tabelaJogador.Posicao = jogadorDTO.Posicao;
            tabelaJogador.Nacionalidade = jogadorDTO.Nacionalidade;
            tabelaJogador.DataNascimento = jogadorDTO.DataNascimento;
            tabelaJogador.Altura = jogadorDTO.Altura;
            tabelaJogador.Peso = jogadorDTO.Peso;
            tabelaJogador.ativo = jogadorDTO.ativo;
            tabelaJogador.UtilizadorCriacao = "";
            tabelaJogador.DataCriacao = DateTime.Now ;
            tabelaJogador.UtilizadorAlteracao = "";
            tabelaJogador.DataAlteracao = DateTime.Now ;

            baseDados.tbJogadores.Add(tabelaJogador);
            baseDados.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Precisava de um método para validar dados que entram através do formulário do website, tipo Verifica se os dados foram lá colocados:

```
public bool InsereDados(JogadorDTO jogadorDTO)
        {
            if (jogadorDTO.Nome == null)
                return false;
            if (jogadorDTO.Altura == 0)
                return false;
            if (jogadorDTO.ativo == false)
                return false;
            if (jogadorDTO.DataNascimento == null)
                return false;
            if (jogadorDTO.Nacionalidade == null)
                return false;
            if (jogadorDTO.NumeroCamisola == 0)
                return false;
            if (jogadorDTO.Peso == 0)
                return false;
            if (jogadorDTO.Posicao == null)
                return false;

            else

                return true;
        }
```

E agora precisava de algo que me dissesse que se aqueles dados são falsos então precisa de os colocar obrigatoriamente no formulário com algum tipo de msg de erro. pensei tipo algo:

`public bool ValidarDados(JogadorDTO jogadorDTO, out string msg)`

Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Acredito que a melhor maneira de validar os campos da tela seria com Jquery [https://jquery.com/]

Answer (score 3):

PedroF, apesar de discodar produdamente da sua escolha de arquitetura (`Entity Framework` com `Repository Pattern`/`DAL` adicional), vou tentar lhe ajudar com a validação.

primerio, faça que a sua entidade, no caso Jogador herde de `IValidatableObject`, então implemente a sua regra de validação no método Validate().

```
public class Jogador : IValidatableObject
{
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public int Altura { get; set; }     
    public DateTime? DataNascimento { get; set; }
    public string Nacionalidade { get; set; }
    public int NumeroCamisola { get; set; }
    public int Peso { get; set; }
    public string Posicao { get; set; }
    public bool Ativo { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult>(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (this.Nome == null)
            yield return new ValidationResult("Propriedade Nome é obrigatoria", new [] { "Nome" });
        if (this.Altura == 0)
            yield return new ValidationResult("Propriedade Altura é obrigatoria", new [] { "Altura" });            
        if (this.DataNascimento == null)
            yield return new ValidationResult("Propriedade DataNascimento é obrigatoria", new [] { "DataNascimento" });
        if (this.Nacionalidade == null)
            yield return new ValidationResult("Propriedade Nacionalidade é obrigatoria", new [] { "Nacionalidade" });
        if (this.NumeroCamisola == 0)
            yield return new ValidationResult("Propriedade NumeroCamisola é obrigatoria", new [] { "NumeroCamisola" });
        if (this.Peso == 0)
            yield return new ValidationResult("Propriedade Peso é obrigatoria", new [] { "Peso" });
        if (this.Posicao == null)
            yield return new ValidationResult("Propriedade Posicao é obrigatoria", new [] { "Posicao" });
        if (this.Ativo == false)
            yield return new ValidationResult("Propriedade Ativo é obrigatoria", new [] { "Ativo" });
    }
}
```

No exemplo acima, como estamos verificando apenas se o campo foi preenchido, o ideal seria utilizar DataAnnotations, então a implementação abaixo também seria valida:

```
public class Jogador : IValidatableObject
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Propriedade Nome é obrigatoria")]
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Propriedade Altura é obrigatoria")]
    [Range(100, 250, ErrorMessage = "Altura deve ser maior que 1.00 e menor que 2.50")]
    public int Altura { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Propriedade DataNascimento é obrigatoria")]
    public DateTime? DataNascimento { get; set; }

    /* Outras Validacoes */

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult>(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var results = new List<ValidationResult>();
        Validator.TryValidateProperty(this.Nome,
            new ValidationContext(this, null, null) { MemberName = "Nome" },
            results);
        Validator.TryValidateProperty(this.Altura,
            new ValidationContext(this, null, null) { MemberName = "Altura" },
            results);
        Validator.TryValidateProperty(this.DataNascimento,
            new ValidationContext(this, null, null) { MemberName = "DataNascimento" },
            results);

        /* Demais Validações */

        if (this.DataNascimento.HasValue && (this.DataNascimento.Value.Year < 1900 || this.DataNascimento.Value.Date > DateTime.Today))
            results.Add(new ValidationResult("Propriedade DataNascimento é invalida", new [] { "DataNascimento" }));

        /* Demais Validações */

        return results;
    }
}
```

A validação é realizada automaticamente quando chamar o SaveChanges();

```
//Input.: DataNascimento = 01/01/1800 (Data Invalida)
public static void CriaRegisto(JogadorDTO jogadorDTO) 
{
    var tabelaJogador = Mapper<Jogador>(jogadorDTO);
    using (var baseDados = new bd_AvesEntities())
    {
        baseDados.tbJogadores.Add(tabelaJogador);
        baseDados.SaveChanges(); //Validation Exception
    }
}
```

Se você preferir, também pode chamar o método `.GetValidationErrors()`

```
//Input.: DataNascimento = 01/01/1800 (Data Invalida)
public static IEnumerable<ValidationResult> CriaRegisto(JogadorDTO jogadorDTO) 
{
    var tabelaJogador = Mapper<Jogador>(jogadorDTO);
    using (var baseDados = new bd_AvesEntities())
    {
        baseDados.tbJogadores.Add(tabelaJogador);
        var erros = baseDados.GetValidationErrors();
        if (!erros.Any()) 
        {
            baseDados.SaveChanges();
        }
        return erros;       
    }
}
```

Na sua camada de apresentação, se estiver utilizando `ASP.NET MVC`, como está usando uma `DTO` como Modelo, à `JogadorController` não irá validar automaticamente, então você terá de adicionar os `ValidationResult` ao seu `ModelState`.

Para exibir os erros na pagina, basta fazer uso do `HttpHelper.ValidationMessageFor`, por exemplo:

```
<div>
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Nome)
</div>
<div>
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Nome)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Nome)
</div>
```

Se estiver utilizando outra tecnologia na sua camada de apresentação, você terá de decidir a melhor forma de exibir os `IEnumerable<ValidationResult>` para o Usuario.